# Implement a IsProcessOpen into an application

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, boolean

I have found the solution for checking if my program is running or not thanks, to DaveK in another thread. But I do not have the reputation to comment, nor do I find a way to message him so that's why I am creating this new question.

I am new to programming and are just starting to create a simple program. I want to deny the program from running multiple instances. Since I do not understand mutex I want to use DaveK's solution.

```
public bool IsProcessOpen(string name = "Opentxtfile")
{
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
}
```

After this I want to use the true or false to ether quit program or just continue running, however I am not able to make this work. When I try to use `IsProcessOpen` in an if statement I get the error:

> Cannot assign to 'IsProcessOpen' because it is a 'method group'

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I have tried to googled my way to the answer but cannot find it..

Edit: rest of the code:

```
public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void S_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        S O = new S();
        O.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Ro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ro R = new Ro();
        R.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

So after some help from another forum it appear I was missing some parenthesis. But now when I'm adding this nothing happends:

```
        public void errormessage()
    {
        if (IsProcessOpen())
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Program is already running!", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide us your code on which you're facing the issue. We need to see your code. Ther error is not in the method but it's in the location where you call this method.

Comment: If you're doing `if(IsProcessOpen)` then you need to change it to `if(IsProcessOpen())` or `if(IsProcessOpen("someprocessname"))`

Comment: Don't google, read the **error message**. It tells you the cause/nature of the error (that's why it is called "error message" and not, for example, "greetings card"). The message tells you *"...because  it is a method group"*. So you are dealing with a method `IsProcessOpen(...)`. Then it tells you also that you tried to assign a value to the method like `IsProcessOpen(...) = somevalue;` which ofcourse is not possible - you can only assign values to variables/field/properties, but not methods... Most likely, you accidentaly used `=` instead of `==` in some if statement...

Comment: Those 4 upvotes amazes me...

Comment: I am sorry, did not mean to insult anyone. As I said, I just started programming so I know very little. I have updated my first post with the rest of the code.

Comment: The 'rest of your code' doesn't even reference `IsProcessOpen` anywhere. Please add the line in your code where you are getting the error.

Comment: I have not added it, because I always get an error. I simply want a if statement: If the bool is true then show message box. If false ignore and continue as usual.. So if my program is already running I want a message box displayed. My namespace is "Opentxtfile" btw..

Comment: Updated the question and added reference part to IsProcessOpen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to use mutex. I'm just posting this to not leave the thread open.

I did not use the mutex in the main menu's code, as I thought I had to. Insted I added it in the Program.cs. Here's the code:

```
namespace My_Program
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static Mutex mx;
        const string singleInstance = @"MU.Mutex";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting(singleInstance);
                MessageBox.Show("The program is already running!", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mx = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, singleInstance);
            }
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Main());
        }
    }
}
```